# What are the reflective thingies called in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for the proper word for these things you wear to avoid being driven over by cars at night.

[image]

Comment: I'd call it "false security". If you want to be seen at night you need a lot more than that. Even a couple of big highly-reflective armbands isn't much - I'd rather put my trust in [proper jacket markings](http://www.satra.co.uk/spotlight/article_view.php?id=343) or keep off unlit roads.

Comment: No, you are wrong sir. Wearing this thing renders you immortal, especially at crosswalks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a reflector, or more precisely, a safety reflector.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_reflector

Yeah, I know, kind of obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I know them as **reflectors**.

Answer (score -1):

Can't tell from photo ..

This is likely a "**Cat's Eye**' reflector, which has distinctive 90-degree angle (from each other) dual reflectors embedded.

This sends a strong light beam directly back towards any focused light source (eg. an approaching car's headlamps).

reference(s):

NZ: [AA gives qualified support to cat's eye speed cameras](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=3580908%20%22%22AA%20gives%20qualified%20support%20to%20cat%27s%20eye%20speed%20cameras)

Comment: Cat's eyes are specifically the things buried in roads with corner-cube reflectors. This is just specular retro-reflective material

Comment: They ARE called that in the UK, but elsewhere the term is used for the material.

Comment: In the UK the name catseye is a trademark of the company founded by the inventor Percy Shaw in 1934  http://patent.ipexl.com/GB/GB436290.html

Comment: @david6: Do you have any sources to back up that usage? The basic principles of [retro-reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroreflector) are the same in OP's object and cat's eyes, but you'd probably need a microscope to discern the equivalent to a single "cat's eye" in the coating of OP's object.

Comment: I will need to search.  I remember the material being developed (too late) for the Apollo program.  But, I have seen tags of this stuff used on school bags in northern Germany, here in NZ, and also in Colorado (US).